# UIView Animation Curves not working for some animations

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I have an app in which I use a lot of animations with ease in/out curves. I use this function in all cases: `UIView animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion`

All these animations are working ok, but now I am trying to add one to a drawer that pops in and out, and for some reason this particular animation is always linear:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
    self.activityBar.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.activityBar.view.frame.origin.y, self.activityBar.view.frame.size.width, 20);
} completion:nil];
```

Why is this animation linear, while other animations with the same option are curved?

This is the view hierarchy for `self.activityBar.view`

```
-UIViewController
 -UIViewController
  -UIViewController (animation code lives here)
   -UIViewController (activityBar)
    -UIView (activityBar.view)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Set old Frame for activityBar Here

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
//Update to the new frame 
self.activityBar.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.activityBar.view.frame.origin.y, self.activityBar.view.frame.size.width, 20);

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
```